# How to move text to middle of a page

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment

How do I move text and header to the middle of a page?

I have tried using `vspace` but I think that is wrong.

This is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\date{May 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage
\begin{center}
\section*{Abstract}
\end{center}
\begin{doublespace}
\rm{SARS COVID-19 is the most devastating pandemic that this millennium has seen. With close to 6 million deaths and 500 million infections globally, the whole world has felt the impact of this virus. From healthcare to education every aspect of life has changed. Without intervention, this virus will continue to claim lives. However, the gaps in knowledge surrounding the current behaviour and future behaviour of SARS COVID-19 make intervention by governments impossible. The aim of this study is to bridge this gap with the help of a modified SIR model and investigate the usefulness of mathematical models in Biology and the field of biomathematics.\\ \par

The modifications made to the SIR model include adjusting the categories (SEIRDV) by including Exposed, Dead and Vaccinated individuals. As well as adding the concept of vital dynamics which takes into consideration natural deaths and births of a particular country, this allows for individuals to move across the categories in a more accurate manner. Our results show.....}
\end{doublespace}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show us relevant code, which we can copy & run. Thanks.

Comment: Please explain further and give a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of what you're trying to do. I don't understand what it would mean for a "header" to be in the middle of a page. How would it still be a header?

Comment: Do you mean the section heading?

Comment: Yes I want to move the section heading and the text.

Comment: Use `\vspace*{2cm}` or some other length you like. Or `\null\vfill ...you content...\vfill`.

Comment: Unrelated, but `\rm` is not a command that takes an argument, and shouldn't be used anyway, as such commands have been deprecated in LaTeX for many decades. See [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361).

Comment: Thank you so much. Your suggestion worked like a dream.

Comment: Also, instead of `\begin{center}\section*{Abstract}...\end{center}` use `\begin{abstract}...\end{abstract}`.

Answer (score 1):

In the future please make sure that your MWE is compilable (it had no title and `doublespace` was undefined).

You can do something along the following lines:

```
\newpage
\mbox{}\vfill
 Text to be placed in the middle of the page (verticaly centered)
\vfill \mbox{}
And this will appear on the next page.
```